# How can I test a response whose body is streamed from within an ecto transaction?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am attempting to write unit tests for an endpoint that streams its response in chunks. I can verify that the contents are fully and correctly streamed when accessed through my browser. But when I access the endpoint through my test suite, the response body is empty.

Example controller action

```
def stream_csv(conn, _params) do
  conn = conn
  |> put_resp_content_type("text/csv")
  |> put_resp_header("content-disposition", "data.csv")
  |> send_chunked(200)

  Repo.transaction(fn ->
    {:ok, conn} = chunk(conn, "csv data part")
  end)

  conn
end
```

Example unit test

```
test "stream endpoint" do
  body = build_conn()
  |> Phoenix.ConnTest.get("/stream_endpoint")
  |> Phoenix.ConnTest.response(200)

  assert body =~ "csv data part"
end
```

This will lead to an assertion failure, where body is an empty binary `""`.

I feel like there should be a way to wait on all the chunks before making assertions, or that I'm probably overlooking something obvious.

**EDIT**

The example I initially wrote works as expected. What seems to complicate things is when `chunk` is called from within a callback provided to `Repo.transaction`. I've updated the question and examples to better reflect the problem.

Comment: Probably won't fix this but you should do `{:ok, conn} = chunk(conn, "...")`.

Comment: It didn't unfortunately, but I'll update the question to show best practice. Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this? If the client is slow, you will keep the transaction open until the client downloads the whole data, which can take a long time.

Comment: Truthfully I'm not sure. I'm new to the phoenix framework, if it looks like a bad idea it probably is a bad idea. Would it be better to first stream to a file, then serve that through a separate channel outside of phoenix?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and tried several ways to get to to work and ended up doing this
[solution using mocks](https://elixirforum.com/t/testing-chunked-responses-from-a-phoenix-endpoint-using-plug-test-or-phoenix-conntest/3471/3?u=zemuldo)

So what is going on is that when we call Plug.Conn.chunk(conn, chunk), plug calls `conn.adapter.chunk`. From there, the chunk should be sent to the server (e.g. cowboy) for further handling. The conn is not aware of the chunk anymore.

To solve this, I moved the chunking to another functions with minimal side effects and easy mockable

```
defmodule MyApp.ControllerUtils do
    use MyaAppWeb, :controller

    @callback chunk_to_conn(map(), String.t()) :: map()
    def chunk_to_conn(conn, current_chunk) do
       conn |> chunk(current_chunk)
    end
end
```

And in the response handler

```
def stream_csv(conn, _params) do
  conn = conn
   |> put_resp_content_type("text/csv")
   |> put_resp_header("content-disposition", "data.csv")
   |> send_chunked(200)

   Repo.transaction(fn ->
   {:ok, conn} = MyApp.ControllerUtils.chunk_to_conn(conn, "csv data part")
  end)

  conn
end
```

Now in your test you mock the chunking function to give you the chunk and use a something like `Agent` store and join the chunks or just assert them as they come.

```
import Mox
defp chunked_response_to_state(chunk, pid) do
  current_chunk = Agent.get(pid, &Map.get(&1, :chunk_key))
  Agent.update(pid, &Map.put(&1, :csv, current_chunk <> chunk))
end
setup do
   MyApp.ControllerUtilsMock
     |> stub(:chunk_to_conn, fn _, chunk -> chunk |> chunked_response_to_state(agent_pid) end)
    {:ok, %{agent_pid: agent_pid}}
end
test "my test", state do
   build_conn.get(somepath)
   whole_chunks = Agent.get(state.agent_pid, &Map.get(&1, :chunk_key))
end
```